# Upgraded node, but getting "SyntaxError: Use of const in strict mode" error

Tags: node.js, selenium, selenium-webdriver, npm, node-modules

I'm running the following versions of node and npm on Amazon Linux ...

```
[myuser@mymachine ~]$ node --version
v8.8.1
[myuser@mymachine ~]$ npm -v
5.4.2
```

After installing my seleniuv-webdriver module via

```
npm install selenium-webdriver
```

I'm running my nodeJS tests, but getting the following error

```
/home/jboss/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/index.js:25
const chrome = require('./chrome');
^^^^^
SyntaxError: Use of const in strict mode.
    at Module._compile (module.js:439:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/jboss/.jenkins/workspace/myco/automated-tests/nodejs/js/js-FF/Optimus-FF.js:2:15)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
```

What else do I need to do to get seleniuv-webdriver to run my commands?